# MySQL utf8_bin collation equivalent for Azure SQL database

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to migrate a MySql application to Azure.
The pricing for Azure's MySql database seems to be quite higher than the "SQL Databases" option so i decided to go for that "SQL database" option.
The last step for the resource set-up is to choose a collation.
In MySQL i use utf8_bin but that collation seems not to be valid for "SQL Database".
Is there an equivalent collation?
I need to store UTF characters, case sensitive and accent sensitive comparison and i almost never sort strings.
I did some research on the internet, but couldn't find any information about Azure's collations

Edit:
After additional researches i've come across 'Latin1_General_BIN2' that should do the job. I'm not sure that 'Latin' can handle all utf8 characters (eg. ʖ, ޖ, etc) - and i did not yet fully grasped the difference between BIN and BIN2 collations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that collation is not UTF8 capable. Up to this moment, existing collations in SQL Server and Azure SQL DB are non-Unicode, with Unicode being enabled (UTF-16) with the NCHAR and NVARCHAR (and SQLVARIANT) data types.
That being said, we are now running a private preview of UTF8 support in SQL Server and Azure SQL DB, so I'd like to further discuss with you. 
Will you be at Ignite? If so please look for me in the SQL Server booth. If not, can you please send me an email to utf8team@microsoft.com?
Thank you!